# Will shutil.rmtree() check for the root directory?

Tags: python, linux, shutil

If I call `shutil.rmtree('/')` Will I nuke my entire drive or does the function have an inner check for this case?

Comment: if you're not root, that will fail with permission denied, else... I wouldn't try that.

Comment: It has no inner check, but the operating system will usually reject it, due to not enough rights (unless it runs with the `root` user).

Comment: why would it check? does `rm` check?

Comment: The `/` directory normally has permissions like `drwxr-xr-x 24 root root`.

Comment: moreover the source code of `shutil.rmtree` is available (written in python, just navigate to it). Check, there aren't any checks.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Actually the `rm` utility in many distros, especially the more end user friendly like Ubuntu, *do* have a check for `/` and even if you run `rm /` as root it will refuse to delete the files. You have to add the option `--no-preserve-root` to shoot yourself in the foot (although I believe it can be fooled relatively easy, it's just to avoid typos on command line). ***[If you want to test this please use a docker container or a VM!]***

Comment: oh like `rm -rf /$FOO` when `FOO` isn't defined :)

Comment: i'm just here to say i'm curious why OP even consider what it will do, wondering what kind of script that line's for

Comment: It's just there to remove some temp files in /tmp, but now I am terrified of what may happen if the /tmp suddenly becomes /

Comment: @Makogan: you should not remove `/tmp` either. Only files *in* the `/tmp`, and even that is not really some task you need to worry about. Let the OS take care of temporary files.

Comment: I have to get rid of the files, the SSD is getting saturated in a single run of the program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rmtree` doesn't have any special logic in it. If you have permissions to `/` (e.g., the program is run by `root`), you will indeed wipe your installation.